# Tag is not saved if i enter random test as a tag to aem page properties

Tags: aem, tagging, aem-6, aem-core-wcm-components

I have created a page and opened page properties. Now i have enterted "test tag" in Tags fields. Tag is added there but i dont see that tag is saved in jcr content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Qyp.png)

please let me know where can see that tag. Need confirmation on whether it will work or not

Comment: Why would you save non-existent tags?